# SVG Rotate Is Negative Angle

Tags: html, svg

I'm currently playing around with some SVG and trying to understand why my SVG is rotating the negative angle. I'm trying to have my red line rotate around my green circle.

Picture and code show what I mean more easily:

0 Degrees:

[image]

90 Degrees:

[image]

0 Degrees Code:

`<svg width="512" height="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(256, 256) rotate(0, 80, 80)">
    <circle r="70" cy="80" cx="80" fill="#6fdb6f" />
    <line x1="160" y1="80" x2="256" y2="80" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:10"/>
  </g>
</svg>`

90 Degrees Code:

`<svg width="512" height="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g transform="translate(256, 256) rotate(90, 80, 80)">
    <circle r="70" cy="80" cx="80" fill="#6fdb6f" />
    <line x1="160" y1="80" x2="256" y2="80" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:10"/>
  </g>
</svg>`

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yapj3ut5/10/)

Comment: The positive rotation direction is clockwise. You're asking it to rotate 90 degrees and it's rotating 90 degrees. (Am I missing something obvious - apologies if so.)

Comment: More likely I'm missing something. I guess I was thinking that on a horizontal plane 90 degrees is up, and so I figured that this should also face up. You're right thought I'm rotating 90 and that goes in a clockwise motion.

Comment: SVG world has different conventions than Math world. Positive rotation is clockwise. The origin is top/left.